# Http response returning two string value in Python

Tags: javascript, python, httpresponse

Hi I have two string in Python like

```
string1 = "['Rilassante piacere', 'Abbraccio vellutato', 'Dosha Vata']";
string2 = "[1, 1, 4]";
```

I have tried passing in the response

```
return func.HttpResponse(string1,string2, status_code=200)
```

But obiviusly it is not possible, should I encode them in JSON?

So my questions are:

- How I can send this two string in HttpResponse in my Python script?
- From the calling the URL 'https://example.com/response' how I can use this response in JS to retrieve these strings?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: what do you mean by this statement "How I can use this response in JS to retrieve these strings?"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code and see if it helps

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"string1":string1, "string2":string1}), status_code=200)
```

you can add as many variables or data as you want inside the JSON object.

to make a request for pure javascript try the below solution

```
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'; this url is the url of your python endpoint
Http.open("GET", url);
Http.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
Http.send();
console.log(Http.response)
response = Http.response // this response should be an object when you use your url
status1 = response['status1']
status2 = response['status2']
```

Comment: Thanks I have updated my question. Having an URL how I can call it and retierieve your two JSON string in Javascript?

Comment: are you using node or just pure vanilla javascript?

Comment: Im using Pure Js

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest as been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

What is wrong

Comment: i have added a change for you

Comment: I don't get nothing even trying your code with your url. Http.response log is just empty

Comment: can you post all your code here?